# How to check 2 defines are the same?

Tags: c++

In MFC application, there is a define for diagnosing the memory leak and so on.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

In afx.h, there exists DEBUG_NEW definition

```
void* AFX_CDECL operator new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine);
#define DEBUG_NEW new(THIS_FILE, __LINE__)
```

How to check new is defined as DEBUG_NEW?

I tried to use

```
#if defined(new) && new == DEBUG_NEW
```

It does not work.

Comment: Do you need to use the result in a macro, or would a runtime check be sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the MFC application code in question, I would change the `#ifdef` contruct to:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#define NEW_REDEFINED
#endif
```

Then you can do your check using `#ifdef NEW_REDEFINED`

Comment: It is not so convenient, the MFC cpp/h files are created by MFC wizard automatically, and that define code is also added by it, so I have to change every files, is there a simple way for it? C++11/C11 new feature for this case?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of redefining a keyword in a macro is a somewhat crazy one and I certainly hope nobody else follows this MFC idea. In that case, a simple

```
#ifdef new
```

would suffice. If the default `new` is used, the keyword won't be defined as a macro.

Depending on what specifically you're after, another option might be to simply use

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
```

trusting that `new` is defined in the form you expect if and only if `_DEBUG` is defined.

But C++ does not have any check that can be performed in an `#if` expression that will tell you if a macro is defined in a particular form.

Comment: Seems to be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know if the two definitions are the same at runtime you could use something like:

```
#include "string.h"
#define STR(s) #s
#define compare(a, b) (strcmp(STR(a), STR(b)) == 0)
```

This would compare the exact string used to define each macro, so it may only be useful in certain cases, consider:

```
#define MY_INT1 int
#define MY_INT2 int
#define MY_INT3 (int)
#define MY_FLOAT float

compare(MY_INT1, MY_INT2)    // Evaluates to true
compare(MY_INT1, MY_INT3)    // Evaluates to false
compare(MY_INT1, MY_FLOAT)   // Evaluates to false
```

Comment: The OP wants to use the result in an `#if` expression, so this won't work.